# PHP: Dumping Memory sqLite Database to File

Tags: php, sqlite

i'm trying to dump a sqLite Database from memory to file (for loggin purposes) but it gives me an error.

I've tried:

```
conn = new SQLite3("dump.db");
$db->backup( $conn );
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Call to undefined method SQLite3::backup()
```

I'm using sqLite Version 3.28.0

Any idea how it would work?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQLite3 extension is old and doesn't have all the functions (`SQLite3::backup` has been introduced arround PHP 7.4).

See the manual page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.backup.php

> As of SQLite 3.27.0 (2019-02-07), it is also possible to use the statement VACUUM INTO 'file.db'; to backup the database to a new file.

If upgrading is not an option, you can simply use [`copy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).